# How to determine the seasonal component order of an ARIMA model?

Tags: arima, interpretation, model-selection, seasonality, acf-pacf

I am implementing  two ARIMA models in R, I used a first order differencing and a seasonal differencing to get the stationary data, like this:

[image]

For the first one I used auto.arima() and got an  ARIMA(2,1,0)(0,1,1)[12]. But the ACF and PACF plots are not quite good:

[image]

So I tried with the significant lags in those plot to determine the nonseasonal part of the ARIMA model and used the SAME seasonal orders as in the auto arima model. I implemented an ARIMA(4,1,3)(0,1,1)[12], just like this:
[image]

and the plots seem to be quite good. But I would like to know how should I interpret the last significant spike in the PACF plot? And, how should I determine the order of the seasonal part? I don't know if following the auto arima model was the right thing to do.

Thank you very much in advance for the answers!